# Drupal 7, Custom Content Type... Does an addon that does this exist?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I rebuilding my companies intranet... we have what's called a portal. Within the portal is pages. Each portal page is either HTML, a PDF or a Video.

Right now... I'm planning on creating 3 seperate content types. One with Text, one with a custom PDF Object for loading in browser and one for a video. So content types like:

```
PAGE content Type 
* Title 
* Image (Icon for content flagged News)
* Text with Teaser

PDF content Type  
* Title  
* Image (Icon for content flagged News)  
* PDF Object (loads PDF in browser) 

VIDEO content Type  
* Title  
* Image (Icon for content flagged News)  
* Video Field

FILEVIEWER content Type  
* Title  
* Image (Icon for content flagged News)  
* FileViewer Viewer
```

Notice... a lot of duplication.

What I'd like to do, and tell me if I'm stupid... is I'd like to have a drop down selector that shows the content type selected, while hiding the rest.

```
COMBINED CONTENT TYPE
* Title  
* Image  
* Select List (Three, or more, choices: Text, PDF, Document, Video)
* Text w Teaser  
* Video Field  
* PDF Field  
* Fileviewer Field
```

It will display the selected content type and hide the others when displayed on the actual node/block. This particular case is simply "Select One type", so I'm not worried about selecting combinations (ie: Text + Video)

I'd just much rather baby one content type... than 3+ content types with near identical layouts.

Question updated. Basically... it's my desire to have one content type instead of 4 (and possibly more). I'm not afraid to make my own custom module, although it would be a learning curve.

Comment: I do agree that it looks like a lot of duplication, but in practice I think the duplication is minimal. Drupal 7 stores it's data per-field, meaning that for instance all image fields in different content types will share a single table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious choice for that functionality would be the [conditional fields module](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields). It's still under development for D7, but you can check if it already supports your use case, or maybe you could even help the maintainer get the D7 version to a stable state.

Comment: I think this might actually do the trick. It is in "dev" status, so... taken with a grain of salt, it's letting me setup dependencies.

Comment: @WernerCD I +1 this solution as it's easier to maintain than a custom module/theme functions ;)

Comment: Yeah... the main reason I was asking if something was out there was that I do want to learn to code some modules... but not yet :)

Comment: It's buggish... but this is spot on what I want.

Comment: @WernerCD: what kind of bugs have you experienced? I'm using it with satisfaction, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure I understand your question, let me rephrase it: you have a content type with fields and a select list. Regarding of the value of this select list, you want to display some fields and hide the others. Correct ?

If so, I would build my fields in a [preprocess function](http://drupal.org/node/223430) and define some variables to display only the fields depending on the value of your select.

Can you clarify a little your question so I can update my answer ?

Comment: Question updated, but yes... your explanation was correct.